# C# Winform : Error while trying to launch TCP client application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, winforms, tcpclient

I have a C# Winform application trying to launch a node server.

However the code for this is written in a different cs file, **Class1.cs** rather than in **Form.cs** itself. I need to keep this separated in different files. Below is my Class1.cs file:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace NodeApp
    {
        class Class1
        {
            static string HOST = "localhost";
            static int PORT = 9999;
            static TcpClient client;
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
           
            public void NodeServer()
            {
                string strCmdText;
                strCmdText = "/C node C:\\Desktop\\Test.js";
                Process process = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Now when I call the function from my **Form.cs** file, like below:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace NodeApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Class1 cl = new Class1();
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cl.NodeServer();
        }
```

am getting `System.NullReferenceException` at  `NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();`.
as no client is connected. But in-order to achieve that, the Node server should be running first correct ?

I was able to achieve this in a console based application where I called the `NodeServer()` method  before the `client.Connect()` method in the Main function

```
 static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            NodeSever();
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Node Server....");
            bool connected = false;
            client = new TcpClient();
            while(!connected)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                try
                { 
                    client.Connect(HOST, PORT);
                    connected = true;
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                   
                }                
            }
        }
```

How can I replicate the same in a Winform application on `Form_load` method (where methods are defined in **Class1.cs** itself). Is `Form_Load` the right event to call the `NodeServer()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix direct member initialisation and constructor logic. This makes it hard to understand the code flow.

This line declares a variable and initializes it:

```
NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
```

It is equivalent to changing the above line to:

```
NetworkStream nwStream;
```

and adding the following as *the first* line of the constructor:

```
nwStream = client.GetStream();
```

This makes it obvious that the client is not initialized.

In your case, just move the connection code to a separate method:

```cs
     public void Connect()
     {
            client = new TcpClient();
            while(!connected)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                try
                { 
                    client.Connect(HOST, PORT);
                    connected = true;
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                   
                }                
            }
     }
```

I also suggest to remove the `static` from the declaration of `client`.

Comment: Ok, but where should I declare and call the Connect() method?. Declare in Form.cs and call it there or declare it in Class1.cs and call it in Form.cs ? Also in which file NetworkStream nwStream; & nwStream = client.GetStream(); should be deifned ? Form1.cs or Class1.cs

Comment: Connect should be in the NodeApp class, and called from Form (with a button, or in the Onload method). The declaration of NetwokStream in Class1 is correct.